# How to change the language displayed in the report of FindBugs

Tags: ant, findbugs

I am using FindBugs to generate a report for my application by using Ant target. In the report, it is mixed with french and english. Does anybody know to generate a report only with english?

Thanks in advance!

Ikeforward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the downloaded version of findbugs, you can just invoke it with

```
LANG="C" ./findbugs
```

Or however you start it, the `LANG="C"` has to be in the environment. This should work on most (all?) operating systems. There is some [documentation about the i18n environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html#tag_08_02) at the Open Group. An example how to do this with Ant is available here:

http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/datamining.html#antexample

(asking Google for "ant findbugs language" had this at it's first result, I hope it works)

Comment: I'd guess this only works on some operating system(s).  Which?  Is "LANG" a FindBugs-specific environment variable?  What is "C"?  Is this documented somewhere? - I can't find it.

Comment: I am using Ant script. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Ed Staub I added some more info to my answer.

Comment: Good! - in particular, note in the ant reference: `<property name="jvmargs" value="... -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=EN ..." />`

Answer (score 1):

According to http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html
I think that you should use the following

```
-Duser.language=en
```

to have the whole thing in English.

Answer (score 0):

Waldheinz's answer may work for you.  The more general answer is that you probably need to change the locale that FindBugs is running in.  The way to do this depends on how you're running it (command line, or from eclipse, or from ant...) and what operating system you're using.  [This page](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/locale/) may provide you with the rest of the info you need - but probably not.  If not, provide specifics.